# No memory access with Android 5

Tags: android, memory, android-5.0-lollipop, memory-access

I am porting an app to Android 5. This app calls

```
dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

and within dir I want to create a subdirectory and work with files in the subdirectory.

With Android 5 I get no read access to dir - this is different to Android 4. So I call

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 42);
```

to gain access - but on emulators running Android 5.0.1 or 5.1 this only opens a blank list with no chance to do anything except tapping return:

[image: screenshot]

What's going wrong?

Comment: I reported this as a bug in the [Android issue list](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=163558)